# SQLite: Inner join on result set

Tags: sqlite, set, inner-join, resultset, exists

In SQLite, is there way to do an inner join of some table on a result set?

Kind of like this *hypothetical query*:

```
SELECT el1,el2 FROM pairs
INNER JOIN (<some_query> AS result) ON el1 IN result AND el2 IN result;
```

The redundant working query should be:

```
SELECT el1,el2 FROM pairs
WHERE el1 IN (<some_query>) AND el2 IN (<same_query>);
```

Where `<some_query>` is:

```
SELECT el FROM set1 INNER JOIN set2 ON set1.el=set2.el;
```

Obviously, the latter looks like it might be very expensive.

What would be the preferred query?

Comment: You could rewrite those `IN` subqueries using exists clauses, but other than that, the second query is a perfectly acceptable way to go.

Comment: Oh ok, so it won't execute the `IN` queries for each `el1,el2`?

Comment: Please tell us what "some query" is.  Please show us the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of `some_query` can be written more efficiently with [`INTERSECT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html):

```
SELECT el FROM set1
INTERSECT
SELECT el FROM set2
```

and if you use a [`CTE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) for `some_query` then for your requirement you can do this:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT el FROM set1
  INTERSECT
  SELECT el FROM set2
)
SELECT el1, el2 
FROM pairs
WHERE el1 IN cte AND el2 IN cte
```